# Find the maximum of the expression, given that $a+b+c+d=100$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

Consider the following expression:

$$S = \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b+7}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{c+7}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{c}{d+7}} +\sqrt[3]{\frac{d}{a+7}}$$

If $a+b+c+d=100$, what is the maximum value of $S$?

Note: $a,b,c,d$ are non-negative reals

I have a strong suspicion that the maximum amount is $4$, but I don't know how to prove it.
It is easy to find values ​​of $a,b,c,d$ such that $S=4$, but it is apparently very difficult to prove that $S\leq 4$

I tried using inequality of means, but I got nothing.For the cube roots I used the geometric mean, I got some inequalities, but they don't help much, for example:

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b+7}} \leq \frac{1+a+\frac{1}{b+7}}{3}$$

I also tried to make some variable changes, like for example:

$$x =b+7, \quad y = c+7, \quad z=d+7, \quad k=a+7$$

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: I brute-forced all the possible *integer* combinations of the four variables, and got a maximum of approximately 4.182 with the combinations (1, 49, 1, 49) or (49, 1, 49, 1).  There may be even larger values for S if non-integer variables are considered.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%2B7%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%2B7%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Bd%2B7%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Ba%2B7%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%3D100%24&p=1), there are quite a few AoPS threads, e.g., [inequality, asymmetric, nonhomogeneous, with a 7 and a radical!](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1876747p12752777) (with this stating the source is "IMO Shortlist $2018$ A$7$, by Evan Chen, Taiwan"), ...

Comment: (cont.)  [Find the maximum value](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1879190p12778750), [2018 IMO shortlist A7 Ingenious solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2244056p17233289), [AM-GM trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2015061p14139820), etc.

Answer (score 5):

Solution from my students Lior Hadassi and Shvo Regavim:

By using Holder and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{a}{b+7}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{a}{a+7}\cdot\tfrac{1}{b+7}\cdot(a+7)}\leq\sqrt[3]{\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{a}{a+7}\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{1}{b+7}\sum_{cyc}(a+7)}=$$
$$=\sqrt[3]{128\left(4-7\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{1}{a+7}\right)\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{1}{a+7}}=\sqrt[3]{128\cdot7\left(\tfrac{4}{7}-\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{1}{a+7}\right)\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{1}{a+7}}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt[3]{128\cdot7\cdot\left(\tfrac{2}{7}\right)^2}=\tfrac{8}{\sqrt[3]7}.$$
The equality occurs for $(a,b,c,d)=(49,1,49,1),$ which says that we got a maximal value.